# Store every selected property from a nested JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object that is structured like this:

```js
{
  question: 'something',
  node: [
    { question: 'something', node: [{ question: 'something' }] },
    { question: 'something' }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is return a certain property from the whole object, for example, return all the question properties like this:

```
[{question: 'somthing'}, ...]
```

Comment: So what would this return? Would it be `['something', 'something, 'something', 'something']`, or `[{question: 'somthing'}, ...]`

Comment: it would return `[{question: 'somthing'}, ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a recursive function returnProperty, which takes the object, property name and an array as argument. It populates the array with desired property items (questionlist in below code).

```js
function returnProperty(obj, propName, propertList=[]){

    if(obj[propName]){
        let propObj = {};
        propObj[propName]=obj[propName];
        propertList.push(propObj);
    }

    if(obj.node && obj.node.length){
        for(let nodeObj of obj.node){
            returnProperty(nodeObj, propName, propertList);
        }
    }
}
let obj = {
  question: 'something',
  node: [
    { question: 'something', node: [{ question: 'something' }] },
    { question: 'something' }
  ]
};
let questionList = [];
returnProperty(obj, 'question', questionList);
console.log(questionList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works with ANY key values. You can have

```
{
  question: 'yx',
  x: [{question: 'x'}]
}
```

and it will extract successfully.

```js
const x = {
  question: 'something',
  node: [
    { question: 'something', node: [{ question: 'fun' }] },
    { question: 'something' }
  ]
}

const keyToCheck = 'question'

const process = (obj) => {
    let output = []
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (key.toString() === keyToCheck) {
            output.push({[keyToCheck]: value})
            continue;
        }

        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            for (const arrObj of value) {
                output = output.concat(process(arrObj))
            }
        }
    }
    
    return output
}

console.log(process(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a recursive function `getSomething(objOrArray)` and a storage array `results`. See if an object or an array is passed in. Apply either `Object.keys(objOrArray)` or `objOrArray.forEach()` to step into the object or array,

- if `this` is an array or a key points to an object or array, call itself `getSomething`
- otherwise if the key is `"question"`, push the key-value pair into `results`.